# Should we have a SQL maintenance plan for TFS Server 2015/2017?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015

We installed TFS Server 2015 Update 2 in September 2016 and we are wondering if we should have a SQL maintenance plan (to rebuild indexes for example) on TFS.

In the documentation, they explained how to set it up, how to setup the backups, but nothing about the maintenance plan.

Is there anyone that tried it out? Is it worth it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't. TFS has its own "Optimize Database" jobs for index maintenance.

Comment: OK thanks for the answer, but where can I make sure that it's running properly?

Comment: It should be a SQL job. The question I have is: Do you have a reason to suspect it's **not** running successfully?

Comment: Well, in the past we made a specific maintenance plan for TFS Server 2008, but for 2015, I have not seen any places where they recommend it... so I did not take any actions about it.

So, this is why I would like to read some documentation or having a proof somewhere that it's running...